# Clearing optimizer weights in keras

Tags: keras

Is it possible to clear optimizer weights in Keras in order to restart the optimizer as some recent papers have shown that this actually produces good results.

Lets say Here's my model below.

```
lstm_model = Sequential()
lstm_model.add(embedding)
lstm_model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm_size, return_sequences=True, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=rec_drop)))
lstm_model.add(Dense(len(label_dict), activation="softmax", name="prediction_layer"))

optimizer = Adamax(1e-2) 

lstm_model.load_weights(model_dir + "model_20.hdf5")
#reset optimizer weights
lstm_model.fit(....)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easily with another `compile`:

```
lstm_model.compile(optimizer=Adamax(1e-2), loss = ....)
```